# F3 problem on MacOSX

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I use mac to play minecraft. But the F3 on this thing does like all windows. Is there a way to change it? and if cant is there another button that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Press FN down while you press down F3 - on a Mac you need to hold down FN to use standard function keys.

See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204436 if you want to change this.